# Share Info betwen brothers components

Tags: reactjs

I have to find a solution to share information between components in React js.
The use case is that in an online store when a guest tries to add a product to his wishlist he should be redirected to the registration page and after registering it should be automatically added to his wishlist.
I tried with window.localStorage and made it work but I was told that it was not necessary to do it this way, the page is a bit complicated and the components do not have common ancestors the component tree is like this.

```
<App>
  <Routes>
    <SearchPage>
      <Gallery>
        <GalleryItem>
          <AddToListButton>
          </AddToListButton>
        </GalleryItem>
      </Gallery>
    </SearchPage>
  </Routes>
</App>
    
<App>
  <Routes>
    <Signin>
    </Signin>
  </Routes>
</App>

<App>
  <Routes>
    <Route>
      <WishlistPage>
        <Wishlist>
        </Wishlist>
      </WishlistPage>
    </Route>
  </Routes>
</App>
```

and I have to pass the button information to the registration page and then make it redirect to its wish list when it registers, apart from useContext what other method could I use?

Answer (score 0):

It depend on the requirements, using localStorage allows you to store user session between tabs, even between sessions.

sessionStorage works similar but it stores data only within single session (for example - one browser tab).

You can try to use React Context API (as you mentioned).

One more is to use centralized store (for example React Redux).

Of course there are some additional browser features like IndexedDb or websql to persist some data for the user, but their support for various browsers can be different.

Answer (score 0):

You have plenty of options, starting with the ones you have out of the box.

- [Lift the state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) The best solution for non complex use cases is to get the state to the parent component and pass down the state value and a function that modifies the state to this sibling components that you want talking to each other.
- [Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) If you have a piece of state that lots of children components are depending on you can create a context, wrap the parent component in a context provider and consume that in the childrens with `useContext`.

Or you can find libraries for state management [here](https://github.com/enaqx/awesome-react#react-state-management)

If this "add to wishlist" action is something that happens in the server I highly recommend [react-query](https://react-query.tanstack.com/). If not, try [zustand](https://github.com/pmndrs/zustand) it's easier to use than [redux](https://redux.js.org/) and feels very similar to context but with less boilerplate and without the need to wrap things in a context provider